# Angular routing not working on Netlify on page refresh

Tags: angular, netlify

I deploy to netlify using `ng build --prod`, and the website works. But when I go to it, it automatically changes the link by adding `/home` onto the end. It still works, but then if I refresh the page or click any links to other pages, it doesn't work anymore. The reason the "/home" is added on is because I have a `RouterModule` set up that has home as it's initial path. Here is the code I have in my "app.module.ts" that sets up routes:

```
 NgbModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'terms-and-conditions',
        component: TermsAndConditionsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'privacy',
        component: PrivacyPolicyComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        component: ContactComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'team',
        component: TeamComponent
      },
      {
        path:'safety',
        component: SafetyComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

So why is it that the build doesn't work for the page linking? It just goes to a "404: page not found" and the console has no errors.

Comment: Maybe you have solved this since Sep 3rd, but the solution I provided should work, it did, at least for me :)

Comment: @AJT_82 I will look into it now.

Comment: @AJT_82 This works! Thank you so much man, I have spent so much time trying to figure this out and couldn't find solutions/explanations anywhere.

Comment: @AJT_82 I have one more question. The official website will be hosted on apache. Do I need to undo these changes and do something else in order to get it working on that?

Comment: related?: https://docs.netlify.com/frameworks/angular/#redirects

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Old question, but for those who might stumble on it on how to enable angular routing in Netlify. Create a file `_redirects` in your `src` folder, add the following to it:

```
/*  /index.html 200
```

in your `angular.json` file add the following to `projects.architect.build.options.assets`

```
{
  "glob": "_redirects",
  "input": "src",
  "output": "/"
}
```

If you happen to use older version of Angular with `angular.cli.json` file, follow this: https://medium.com/@mgd4375/how-to-enable-angular-routing-in-a-netlify-deployment-with-the-angular-cli-e2eda69f1b5b where you do the equivalent change in `angular.cli.json` file, i.e add `"_redirects"` to the corresponding `assets` array.

Comment: This answer is still relevant 18 months later! Thank you.

Comment: Still works in 2021 December !

Comment: Still works in 2022 September !

Comment: What is the meaning of glob?

Comment: Still works in 2023 March !

Comment: Tested in angular 15+ and still works. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you this is working in 2024 using angular 17. I will add that it angular.json now looks like this    "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/_redirects"
            ],

Answer (score 18):

**Enable Angular Routing in Netlify deployment with the Angular CLI**

> Getting 404 on Refresh Page

1. Open angular.json
2. Under assets, add _redirects. This lets the resultant dist folder from a build include your soon-to-be _redirects file.`<project-name>.architect.build.options.assets`

   [image]
3. In the src folder, add _redirects with the following line. Netlify uses this to redirect to index no matter what, allowing angular routing to take over.
   [image]
4. Deploy! You’re done!

Comment: Just for a help. If someone got an error when build the project after adding this line. Use ```src/_redirects```

Comment: Working perfectly in January 2023 with @shehan96 tip by adding "src/_redirects" instead of just "_redirects".

Comment: In my case, using Angular version (Angular CLI: 16.1.8), i have put a "src/" before "_redirects", resulting in: "src/_redirects".

"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/_redirects"
            ],

Answer (score 3):

try Build command: `ng build --prod --base-href ./` and add file to root project *netlify.toml*:

```
# A basic redirects rule
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. It has the same error as before.

Answer (score 2):

I had named my build directory wrongly from the original directory name i used to
create the project

1. In your angular.json check under the projects property for the name of the
   build directory, in my case **bci**
2. So your **Publish directory** should be **dist/bci** on netlify

Answer (score 2):

Incase anyone's looking for a solution without having to create a _redirects file.

You can solve the issue by using the hash routing strategy. Your URLs will look somewhat like this `name.netlify.app/#/hello/login` and all you need to do is specify `{useHash: true}` when importing your `RouterModule` e.g

```
...
imports: [
   RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and fixed it using solution of @AT82

plus

```
project.<app-name>.architect.build.outputPath: "dist/"
```

because mine was set by default as `dist/<app-name>`

or

Change the netlify "Publish directory" under "Build & deploy > Continuous deployment > Build settings" to match outputPath in angular.json

Answer (score 0):

Although most answers do the trick for the redirection, I suggest following [**the official Netflify documentation**](https://docs.netlify.com/frameworks/angular/#redirects)

Answer (score 0):

Angular with NX

1. create new file _redirects
2. Add below line in _redirect file

   /*  /index.html 200

3.open project.json
ex: apps\my-app\project.json

4.add path at targets.build.options.assets :

```
"assets" :[
 "apps/my-app/src/_redirects"
]
```